# How to choose right source for x86 Assembly Language

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I want to dive computer world, that is why i want to learn x86 Assembly. I found some books for source. But i don't know if they will help me. How should i start and where should i. These are books that i found. There are pdf pages for these books, but i don't know it is forbidden to share or not.

1. Programming from the Ground Up.
2. 64 Bit Intel Assembly Language Programming for Linux.
3. X86 Assembly Language and C Fundamentals.
4. Assembly Language Step-By-Step - Programming with Linux, 3rd edition.
5. Guide to Assembly Language Programming in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about computer architecture in general, then the choice of x86 sources becomes less important.   Understanding the ways, abilities and limitations of an architecture is critical to this sort of programming.

If you are new to programming, before diving into computer architecture, you should learn a hassle-free computer language.   *Processing* seems to be quite good.   Most production languages (Java, c++, ...) are a bad choice because they require too much decoration for the task at hand.   *Processing* is free for just about any device, has a free online book, and a printed one available.

Good luck; it is a lot of fun.   I have been programming for a living for over 30 years, and still enjoy it.

Comment: IMO C is a good language to learn before asm.  It's the language of low-level systems programming on Unix and to some degree Windows, so system call docs are in C terms.  Also, C's pointers exactly model asm pointers for "normal" CPUs.  And C compiles pretty straightforwardly to asm: for example, if I want to get a compiler to emit a certain instruction for an example, I can usually write a C function that takes args and returns a value that compiles to a one or a few instructions, including the one I want.

Comment: But if you try to use them, the dreaded Undefined Behaviour strikes and your house might burn down.   But yes, a simple C compiler like Plan9's or even gcc pre 3.0...

Comment: Thanks for your helping. I already use Processing, and i made tetris, snake etc. But it is not for me. I want to know how computer works. Is there any source that you recommend for learning computer architecture?

Comment: That's true, you'd have to use `gcc -fno-strict-aliasing` for an asm-like pointer model for the C abstract machine.  Usually if you're just looking at a single C function, you can still get the asm you want despite UB, but obviously you should avoid it if you're actually writing C as part of a C program, not an experiment in asm.

Comment: "Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach" by David A Patterson and John L. Hennessy is the best one IMO. A beginner might want to start with "Computer Organization and Design:THE HARDWARE/SOFTWARE INTERFACE" by the same authors

Comment: @forevl: If you have an x86 Linux system that you already use, the PGU book is pretty good, and released for free.  It's a bit old, and only covers 32-bit, but 32-bit mode is probably the simplest.  Learning the new stuff in x86-64 and the calling convention differences later is fine.  I don't know anything about any of the other books.  It covers some about how computers work, but yeah TSG's suggestion of Patterson and Hennessy gets more into computer architecture, which is really interesting once you know how to program in asm.

Comment: @forevl: yes, you can run Linux in a VM.  You don't need a 32-bit install of Linux, though; you can use a normal x86 Linux system with a 64-bit kernel and user-space, i.e. x86-64.  That will have 32-bit libraries and support 32-bit system calls.  (Unless you're on Windows Subsystem for Linux, where the `int 0x80` 32-bit interface *doesn't* exist.  If you have that, you might prefer not to mess around with a VM and just learn x86-64 Linux directly.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Is there way to know that if i have that? What is this about? And can i use any Linux distribution?

Comment: @forevl: if you're using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 with a Linux user-space under a compat layer in the Windows kernel, instead of a real GNU/Linux install inside a real VM, you're using WSL.  Otherwise you're not.  If you're somehow not sure, `cat /proc/version` to get the kernel version string.  It will include Microsoft for WSL, apparently: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/423